# React navigation pops to top when redux store is updated

Tags: react-native, react-redux, react-navigation-v5

I'm working on edit profile when i change my redux store the navigation stack pops to top screen in stack.Like if i'm on edit profile screen on redux state change it goes back to settings screen.
what am i doing wrong here?

**Reducer**

```
case TYPES.UPDATE_PROFILE:
  const data = {...state};
  const payload = actions.payload;
  return {
    ...state,
    user: {
      ...data.user,
      first_name: payload.first_name,
      last_name: payload.last_name,

      ['user_info']: {
        ...data.user.user_info,
        gender: payload.gender,
        date_of_birth: payload.date_of_birth,
        phone_number: payload.phone_number,
      },
    },
  };
```

**action code**

```
dispatch({
  type: TYPES.UPDATE_PROFILE,
  payload: params,
});
```

Navigation file (using react navigation v5)

```
 function ProfileScreens() {
return (
  <Stack.Navigator>
    <Stack.Screen
      name="Settings"
      component={Settings}
      options={{headerShown: false}}
    />
    <Stack.Screen
      name="ProfileView"
      component={Profile}
      options={{headerShown: false}}
    />
    <Stack.Screen
      name="EditProfile"
      component={EditProfile}
      options={{headerShown: false}}
    />
  </Stack.Navigator>
);
```

}

can someone please help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use React history to redirect in action creator-

```
import history from "./history"

dispatch({
  type: TYPES.UPDATE_PROFILE,
  payload: params,
});

 history.push("path after redirection");
```

history.js

```
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history'; 


export default createBrowserHistory();
```

For latest React version

Comment: I'm using React Native and i don't want to redirect any where i just want to update redux state and stay on the same screen